# Python - Replicate mapply() functionality from R in python

Tags: python, r, pandas, apply, mapply

I calculated percentiles of feature values in one of the rows of the dataset in R using mapply().
Here's the R code:

```
library(MASS)
boston = Boston
# Suburb(s) with lowest median home value
low.medv <- boston[boston$medv == min(boston$medv),]
low.medv
#        crim zn indus chas   nox    rm age    dis rad tax ptratio  black lstat medv
# 399 38.3518  0  18.1    0 0.693 5.453 100 1.4896  24 666    20.2 396.90 30.59    5
# 406 67.9208  0  18.1    0 0.693 5.683 100 1.4254  24 666    20.2 384.97 22.98    5

# quantile ranks for the values of medv suburbs
perc = data.frame(round(mapply(function(x, y) ecdf(x)(y), boston, low.medv1),3), 
                  row.names = paste(rownames(low.medv1),'_P',sep = ""))
```

***Desired Output***

```
perc
#        crim    zn indus  chas   nox    rm age   dis rad  tax ptratio black lstat  medv
# 399_P 0.988 0.735 0.887 0.931 0.858 0.077   1 0.057   1 0.99   0.889  1.00 0.978 0.004
# 406_P 0.996 0.735 0.887 0.931 0.858 0.136   1 0.042   1 0.99   0.889  0.35 0.899 0.004
```

***Questions:***
I'm trying to replicate this in python.

1. How can I replicate the above in python?
2. Is there a function that has the same functionality as mapply() in python?

Here's the python code for reproducing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore as ptile
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
df['medv'] = boston.target
df.columns

# Suburb(s) with lowest median home value
low_medv = df[df.medv == min(df.medv)]
low_medv
```

It can be done with two for loops:

```
perc = pd.DataFrame()
for c in low_medv.columns:
    for i in low_medv.index:
        perc.loc[i,c] = round(ptile(df[c], low_medv.loc[i,c]),3)
# ptile calculates the percentile rank of a given value
perc
```

But is this the most efficient way?

Comment: What does `mapply` do?

Comment: @QuangHoang https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mapply

Comment: What's the `ptile` function in your code?

Comment: @QuangHoang,  ptile calculates the percentile rank of a given value. (What percentile a value is in a data series.)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has `rank`:

```
# min(df.medv) is not vectorized
low_medv = df[df.medv == df.medv.min()]

(df.rank(method='average',pct=True)
   .loc[low_medv.index]
   .mul(100).round(3)
)
```

Output:

```
       CRIM      ZN   INDUS   CHAS     NOX      RM    AGE    DIS     RAD     TAX  PTRATIO       B   LSTAT   medv
398  98.814  36.858  75.791  46.64  84.486   7.708  95.85  5.731  87.055  86.067   75.198  88.142  97.826  0.296
405  99.605  36.858  75.791  46.64  84.486  13.636  95.85  4.150  87.055  86.067   75.198  34.980  89.921  0.296
```